# Banco de dados - Mesclar tabelas com estruturas diferentes

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

A minha principal dúvida é: qual a melhor maneira de fazer e não quais comandos utilizar. O que preciso, basicamente, é o seguinte:

Possuo duas tabelas com estruturas diferentes, em bases de dados diferentes. Por exemplo:

Banco de dados 1 - Tabela cliente
estrutura: id - nome - cpf - telefone - salario

Banco de dados 2 - Tabela pessoa
estrutura: id_pessoa - nome - email - telefone - cidade - cpf - profissao

O que preciso, é conseguir inserir os dados da primeira tabela (cliente) na segunda tabela (pessoa). Onde, por exemplo, cliente.id seria associado à pessoa.id_pessoa ; a coluna cliente.nome seria inseria na coluna pessoa.nome, cliente.salario poderia ser definido pelo usuário para nao ser associado à nenhuma coluna da tabela pessoa, e sim criar essa coluna como uma nova... Ou seja, associar cada coluna de uma tabela à uma coluna de outra tabela, ou criando uma nova coluna na segunda tabela, informando associação à associação.

Alguém possui alguma ideia/sugestão de como fazer? O sistema está sendo feito em PHP.

Comment: Que tal não fazer nada disto? Pelo menos na forma descrita, parece muito confuso para não atingir objetivo algum. Claro que pode existir algum motivo, mas não está claro na pergunta, então só posso dizer para simplificar e evitar fazer assim. Com mais informações daria para sugerir algo mais preciso. Com perguntas sem detalhes só poderá receber respostas sem detalhes.

Comment: Concordo com o @bigown, não faça... Repense um pouco sua estrutura e o motivo para você ter o mesmo dado em tabelas diferentes? Não seria mais simples só falar que a tabela cliente tem a chave externa id_pessoa ?

Comment: Concordo com o @bigown mas uma outra opção, se usar uma tabela só não for possível é usar uma tabela de relacionamento. Ao invés de batalhar pra mesclar dados em tabelas com estruturas diferentes não rola de usar uma tabela só associando cliente.id e pessoa.id_pessoa e fazer os relacionamentos necessários na consulta?

Comment: Preciso fazer um processo de integração de dados, essa é a razão. Duas tabelas 'mescladas' que originam uma nova. As duas anteriores são removidas depois disso e a nova tabela é criada em uma base nova. Ou seja, copiei a tabela pessoa para o novo repositório, integrado. Agora preciso adicionar os dados da tabela cliente nessa tabela.

Comment: Você quer apenas selecionar todos os registros da tabela do banco de dados anterior e subir os dados para nova tabela em um novo banco é isso?

Comment: associando a tabela anterior com a nova. A tabela anterior deixará de existir?

Comment: Você vai fazer a inserção de uma vez só? ou é cada vez que o cliente usa o sistema, você quer que isso aconteça aos poucos?

Comment: Uma única vez, depois a tabela anterior deixará de existir. Pegar a tabela de uma base e inserir em outra tabela, de outra base, é tranquilo. Mas não posso inserir a tabela inteira, justamente por que a estrutura das duas é diferente...e algumas colunas não existem na tabela nova e outras não serão populadas ( Null) por que não existem na primeira tabela... Ou seja, usuário teria que selecionar uma coluna da primeira tabela e em seguida selecionar a coluna da nova tabela, na qual deseja inserir os dados ( e uma opção para criar uma nova coluna quando n existir). só vejo essa solução.

Comment: Ou seja terá que fazer um sistema para que o usuário cadastre de forma manual os registros que não baterem naquele momento. Por exemplo: ele faz um loop e sai registrando... ai bate uma inconformidade e o usuário escolhe se cria uma nova coluna ou usa uma coluna existente. Ai depois o sistema continua registrando até ter alguma nova inconformidade... é isso?